# Unity C# enum, Unsupported type error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity C#, 
This enum code make errors on the console at runtime only.

```
[System.Flags]
private enum ActionSet : long
{
    Sit      = 0x0000000000000001,
    Stand    = 0x0000000000000002,
    Walk     = 0x0000000000000004,
    Sleep    = 0x0000000000000008,
    Run      = 0x0000000000000010,
    Happy    = 0x0000000100000000,
    Sleepy   = 0x0000000200000000,
    Gloomy   = 0x0000000400000000
}
```

The error is:

> Unsupported enum type ‘Character.ActionSet’used for field 'blrah blrah' in class ‘Character’

Unity C# support int type only?
And no problem to use this code?

Comment: Have you checked the [Unity3d answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/560358/unsupported-enum-type.html)? The `long` data type may be unsupported. Try switching to an `int` or can you explain the use case for a `long`?

Comment: Thanks. I separate upper 8 and lower 8 digits logically as one state variable. Now I see. I'll divide it into two ints.

Comment: Is there any formal documents about unity's enum support type?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the [Mono compatibility page](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) the Unity3D Enum type should be compatible with .NET 2.0. .NET 2.0 does not have this problem AFAIK. Splitting out your enum into multiple enums or using a static class with const are probably the paths of least resistance.

Comment: I am also encountering this issue. As mentioned above, I believe enums of type long are supported, it pretty much says so in this [Unity Enumerations Video](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/enumerations).

Comment: Sorry to post another comment, but it seems the problem occurs if you have a member variable of the enum type, the issue does not occur if you have a local variable of the enum type. Which seems odd.

Comment: According to (https://forum.unity.com/threads/unsupported-enum-type-unityengine-networking-types-networkid.359462/) : `The issue is Unity's enum serializer expects a 32bit value only.`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is Unity's enum serializer [expects a 32bit value only](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unsupported-enum-type-unityengine-networking-types-networkid.359462/#post-2370283).
Some possible workarounds:

- Use [NonSerialized] attribute.
- Store the value in a underlying type (long in your example).

Answer (score -2):

Just like it was mentioned before, Unity's enum serializer expects a 32 bit value only.

[A unity forum similar to this suggests using ulong instead](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unsupported-enum-type-unityengine-networking-types-networkid.359462/)

Comment: It’s better to put the body of the text in the answer here rather than link elsewhere.

Comment: @AlBlue yeah but the whole discussion might give him a better context and understanding if he reads it.

Comment: It’s more likely that this answer will be downvoted or deleted, and since the original asker was in October 2019 I’m not sure it will be something that gets read now — and when the forum goes away or the post is lost then this answer will add no value.

Comment: @AlBlue Then it shouldn't matter if its in the body or not. and I suggested ulong in the link text itself, the link is there for just more info. ill leave it upto them :). Not gonna cry if this gets deleted or downvoted, just sharing what I know lol.

Comment: I’m sorry you feel that way — I was trying to help explain why it’s likely the answer would be downvoted and the fact that link-only answers are not preferred on this site. See for example https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers for details.

Comment: @AlBlue No worries brother, its fine. Although I don't necessary agree that links can't be helpful but if its the stack's rule, I gotta follow it. I was actually gonna comment instead but it requires 50 point thingy to comment and I'm not really a regular stack user. Its all goods though